# List of running processes

Tags: bash, process, ps

There is a `top` command to show running processes. I would like to print sorted list of unique values in field `COMMAND`. There is my solution for this task

```
$ top -b -n 1 | tail -n+8 | awk '{print $12}' | cut -d'/' -f 1 |  sort | uniq
```

However, this is too wordy command for so simple purpose. Is there a simpler solution for the task?

***PS:*** I can use `ps` instead of `top`, but it returns too noisy format:`chrome` vs `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable- features=LinuxObsoleteSystemIsEndOfTheLine<LinuxObsoleteSystemIsEndOfTheLine --lang=en-US --force-`...  this is just beginning of command.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend pouring over through the documentation for `ps`.

These might be an interesting start:

```
ps -eo comm=,
```

or

```
ps -eo cmd=,
```

You probably want the first one.

If you want absolutely fine-grained control, read the `Name`: line from `/proc/nnnnnn/status` (or parse the string between the parens in `stat`) where `nnnnn` represents all-numbers. For the full commandline, read `/proc/nnnnnn/cmdline`, and translate the NUL bytes in the file to space characters.

Note that `ps` on BSD (provided as part of that ecosystem) is a little different to Linux's version (supplied to Linux by the procps-ng project) and the two interpret their options a little differently. Worth noting if you're ever on *BSD.

Comment: The output with chrome and the full path etc is the commandline (cmd in ps) which shows everything while comm is the shortname out of the status procfs file. For what you want to see, comm is what you are after.

The c key  or the -c command line in top toggles the cmd and comm output, in case you wanted to change it there too.

Note, that top remembers the toprc settings even in batch mode. This means if you toggle the comm/cmd option, save toprc then run in batch mode you get a better output. I always recommend using the -o flags in ps if you are looking for specific fields.